# Reducing tasks to complete when creating child dataframes in Dask

Tags: python, dask, dask-dataframe

I am trying to understand the "best practice" when creating child dataframes in dask in which I haven't found within the dask documentation and best practice articles.

Let's say I have a really big dask dataframe called `df` which has many tasks behind it in order to create it. Then I need to perform some operation on it which I want to store in a child dataframe called `child_df` then join `child_df` back to `df`.

When the join has completed I then need to use `.compute()` to get the data back into pandas and carry on my work.

I believe that `child_df` will be duplicating the amount of tasks that it takes to create `df` and thus I am wondering is there a way I can create `child_df` without rerunning the tasks that create `df`? Is my thinking correct that `child_df` doubles the work?

This is a very simplified view of what I am trying to achieve so I understand I could call `df.compute()` then work off that on the `child_df` but in my case that will not work due to `df` not being able to fit in memory and being filtered down further on in the process.

Hope this makes sense :)

[image: snip of task duplication]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you will not be duplicating the tasks. The "child" does indeed need all the upstream tasks if you were to compute it alone, but when you join it back with the "parent" dataframe, dask uses the unique keys associated with every operation and combination of arguments to only calculate each intermediate result only once and use it as many times as necessary.

(In come cases, you may genuinely get some duplication and in fact want this to be the case, should for example one of your workers become slower than the others. This technique to improve performance and parallelism happens relatively rarely and not at all if you are pressured for memory in the system)

Comment: Perfect, thanks for clearing that up mdurant!